# Add filter button to custom post type in admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, wp-admin

We use a 3rd party custom post type for events in which they have removed the ability to filter the posts.

[image: Events List]

I would like to add the option to filter the posts by event date. I have found plenty of examples on adding a filter but I can't find anything for adding the "Filter" button.

[image: Posts List]

Does anyone know if it is possible to add this button and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my case I found how they were hiding the date dropdown and filter button.

```
.events-cal .tablenav select[name=m], .events-cal #post-query-submit {
    display: none;
}
```

At least I can overwrite their CSS and get both of those functions back.
Thank you.

Comment: It crossed my mind, that this could be the case, but I doubted the plugin author would use it because the usual way is to use the filter, but I was wrong ;-) Please accept your answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the usual *months dropdown*, then most likely the plugin might be  disabling it via the following filter:

```
/**
 * Filters whether to remove the 'Months' drop-down from the post list table.
 *
 * @since 4.2.0
 *
 * @param bool   $disable   Whether to disable the drop-down. Default false.
 * @param string $post_type The post type.
 */

 if ( apply_filters( 'disable_months_dropdown', false, $post_type ) ) {
     return;
 }
```

You could try to override it with:

```
add_filter( 'disable_months_dropdown', function( $disable, $post_type )
{
    return 'event' === $post_type ? true :$disable;
}, 999, 2 );
```

where you might need to adjust the post type slug and priority to your needs.

Comment: Thanks but no luck. I checked the plugin and couldn't find a filter using `'disable_months_dropdown'`. I found I could create/add other filters, it's just getting the "filter" submit button back to process it.